# Saving and Recalling a model with a custom loss function in tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow, serialization, tf.keras

I have the following custom loss function for an LSTM model in tensorflow:

```
#Custom Loss Function

def custom_loss(y_true, y_pred):
    # Calculate the aggregate difference between predictions and actuals
    loss = K.sum(K.abs(y_true - y_pred))  
    
    return loss

# Define a composite loss function that combines MSE and custom loss

def composite_loss(alpha):
    def nested_loss(y_true, y_pred):
        mse_loss = K.mean(K.square(y_true - y_pred))  # Mean Squared Error
        custom_loss_val = custom_loss(y_true, y_pred)
        composite = mse_loss * alpha + custom_loss_val  # You can adjust the weight with 'alpha'
        return composite
    return nested_loss


  # Adjust the weight of custom loss relative to MSE as needed
    
alpha = 0.5
```

My model compile looks like this

```
model = Sequential()

model.add(LSTM(128, return_sequences=True, input_shape=(X_train.shape[1], 1)))
model.add(Dropout(0.3))
model.add(LSTM(64,return_sequences=True))
model.add(Dropout(0.3))
model.add(LSTM(32,return_sequences=True))
model.add(Dropout(0.3))
model.add(LSTM(16,return_sequences=False))
model.add(Dense(1))


# Create an instance of the custom loss class

optimizer = Adam(lr=0.001)

model.compile(loss=composite_loss(alpha), optimizer=optimizer)
```

My save looks like this:

```
utils.get_custom_objects()['composite_loss'] = composite_loss
model.save('SYM-Revised-CAS-30')
```

My re-load like this:

```
model = load_model('SYM-Revised-CAS-30',custom_objects={'composite_loss': composite_loss})
```

When I reload my model I get this error:

```
ValueError: Unknown loss function: 'nested_loss'. Please ensure you are using a `keras.utils.custom_object_scope` and that this object is included in the scope. See https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/keras/save_and_serialize#registering_the_custom_object for details
```

I've tried several different approaches to fix including putting the loss functions in a class.   Always different errors.

Can someone give some guidance?

Comment: At the time of `load_model`, if you pass `compile=False`, does it work?

Answer (score 0):

After incredible difficulty I found that I could save the model without the custom loss function   However, in order to avoid the keras save function from trying to save the custom loss function I had to save model architecture and weights only separately as json files.

Here is the code:

To Save:

```
# Save the model architecture as JSON
model_json = model.to_json()
with open("SYM-Revised-CAS-30.json", "w") as json_file:
    json_file.write(model_json)

# Save the model weights only
model.save_weights("SYM-Revised-CAS-30_model_weights.json")
```

To reload:

```
from tensorflow.keras.models import model_from_json

# Load the model architecture from JSON
with open('SYM-Revised-CAS-30.json', 'r') as json_file:
    model = model_from_json(json_file.read())

# Load the model weights
model.load_weights('SYM-Revised-CAS-30_model_weights.json')
```